# Convert HTML table to PHP array - problem with merge text

Tags: php, html

I have a little problem. I must convert in PHP from table html to array or json. My array always have two columns and N rows. I use:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$xml->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>'.$content);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
$table =$xpath->query("//*[@class='".$autoAttributeHtmlClass."']");

$length = $table->length;

$j = 0;
$attrArr = array();
for ($i=0; $i <= $length-1; $i++) { 
  $element = $table->item($i);
  $rows = $element->getElementsByTagName("tr");

  foreach ($rows as $row) 
  { 
    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td'); 

    $attrArr[$j]['attr'] = rtrim($cols->item(0)->nodeValue, ':');
    $attrArr[$j]['val'] = htmlspecialchars($cols->item(1)->nodeValue);
    $j++;
  }
}

echo json_encode($attrArr);
```

All is good until in column is only clear text. When in column is additional html code (for example: `<div>`, `<span>`, `<p>`, `<li>`, etc.) inner texts are merge

Example HTML table:

```
    <table class="test">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Col1</td>
            <td>Micro Tower</div></td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td>Col2</td>
            <td>
                <p>Micro-ATX</p>
                <p>Mini-ITX</p>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Col3</td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <span>Test1</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>Test2</span>
                </div>              
            </td>
        </tr>       
</tbody>
</table>
```

In case of secound row in nodeValue (PHP) I have a merge: `Micro-ATXMini-ITX`

In third row in nodeValue (PHP) I have a merge: `Test1Test2`

Any idea? I must have a separator in between text - now is not readable (space, coma or semicolon)

Comment: Could you provide full example with all needed variables?

Answer (score 0):

Try `.textContent` insted of `.nodeValue`

Comment: Also try to remove htmlspecialchars